# Drupal creates links instead thumbnails for big files

Tags: drupal-7, thumbnails

I have a content type with image filed and thumbnail for the image style. When I upload small images (up to 1.8 MB) Drupal 7 Creates thumbnails but when I upload big images Drupal creates links instead thumbnails (and the links work).

I think the problem is not the size of the file because the files could be uploaded. There are not restrictions for max and min image resolution.

Any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Enable the SysLog core module and see if there any errors in the log (admin/reports/dblog).

Comment: There are not errors. Actually I just saw that the alternate text for the image is used for link and under the alternate text field is written that "This text will be used by screen readers, search engines, or WHEN THE IMAGE CANNOT BE LOADED". Maybe there is time limitation for loading and this could be the reason for big images. Any other ideas how I can solve the issue?